# How do you authorize Outlook.com with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-app, outlook.com

Cut my life into pieces, this is my last resort.

Seriously, I can't find this info anywhere! I thought Graph supported Outlook.com.  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480656/outlook-rest-api-vs-microsoft-graph) which referenced the Outlook Api vs the Graph Api, but how do I authorize an Outlook.com account for this?

I'm sending the user to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` with the parameters:

```
response_type = code
client_id = <my client id>
redirect_uri = <my redirect_uri>
state = <csrf>
resource = https://outlook.office.com/
```

to sign in.  It takes them to the Office 365 sign in, and when you type `@outlook.com`, it tries to redirect you, only to go back to the 365 login page and do it all over.

I can authorize Office 365 just fine, but not Outlook.com.  I can provide more info if needed, I just figure I'm hitting the wrong endpoint or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently we have two versions of the authentication endpoint. The version less endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize) only supports work and school accounts (Office365) the v2.0 auth endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) supports both work and school and personal accounts. 
To use a personal account (hotmail.com, outlook.com, live.com) with Microsoft Graph, you start by registering you app in apps.dev.microsoft.com, then follow the instructions in this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-scopes/. Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response, I'm working on it.  So will the app I register in the App Registration Portal (as opposed to Azure AD) still work with 365 accounts?  Or do I need to maintain two registrations, one for each account type?

Comment: Any app that you have registered in the Windows Azure portal will continue to work, only for Office 365 (work and school accounts). Soon, you will be able to manage those from the new portal as well. Any app that you register in the App Registration Portal (apps.dev.microsoft.com) will work for both personal (Hotmail.com, outlook.com, live.com) and work and school (Office 365).