# Obtain access token for both Microsoft Graph and individual service API endpoints (Outlook REST APIs etc.)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I spent some time playing around with Azure AD OAuth 2.0.

An access token obtained with scope `https://outlook.office.com/mail.read` throws `401 Unauthorized` when used with Microsoft Graph.

Similarly, an access token obtained with scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read` throws `401 Unauthorized` when used with Outlook REST API endpoints.

Also, I get an error if I mention both the scopes while authorizing a user.

Is it possible to have access tokens that allow access to both Microsoft Graph and Outlook REST API endpoints?

I am building an emailing app. Initially, I will build basic features like syncing/sending emails.

I will be using Microsoft Graph, since it supports all that I need presently and [Microsoft recommends it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480656) over individual service API endpoints.

I am worried about future. The OAuth access tokens that I will obtain at present will have scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read`. In future, it may happen that a new feature I want to build is not supported by Microsoft Graph but it is supported By Outlook REST API endpoints. At such time I would want to use the Outlook REST API endpoints.

Do I have to maintain two sets of OAuth access token for every user? Also asking every user to re-auth is not a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the RefreshToken to get an AccessToken to the individual endpoints with the same scopes as authorized when you requested the graph access (scopes).

E.g. If you requested `Mail.Read` (shortname for `https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read`) you can get back to the token issuing endpoint with the refresh_token with `scope="https://outlook.office.com/mail.read"` and get an accesss_token for this endpoint.

Comment: Thanks. That's great news!