# How to get Outlook Access token?

Tags: rest, salesforce, outlook-restapi

I'm using the outlook calendar rest api from Salesforce. To continuously leverage the calendar API I need to get authorisation code, access and refresh token.

I have been able to get the Authorisation code by hitting the API. How to get the access token using development code to use the outlook calendar rest API.

Comment: Could you share your code for getting the authorization code?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the list of AAD authentication libraries here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries

Answer (score -2):

I found this tutorial in **Python** very helpful for getting access codes:

**This tutorial uses [Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480656/outlook-rest-api-vs-microsoft-graph) (which covers several Microsoft products including Microsoft Outlook) rather than the outlook REST API (which covers just Outlook).**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial

At first, I thought setting up a Django server was overkill. Then I realized that I wanted a way for my Python instance to capture the access code after going through single-sign-on.  (I MUST use my browser for single-sign-on because my institution uses multi-factor authentation.) Having a Django server is a natural way to do this.

So I created a new PyCharm Django project (which is straight-forward in PyCharm) and began following the tutorial.

I found it essential to continue following the tutorial all the way through displaying my emails to avoid getting authentication errors -- deviate from the tutorial, and I got error messages (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878657/invalidaudience-error-returned-when-invoking-outlook-rest-api)) that were unpenetrable.