# 'InvalidAudience' error returned when invoking Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook-restapi

We have a Web Add-in in Outlook that has the ReadWriteMailbox permissions. And we use following code to get REST Token successfully:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result))
```

but we got 'InvalidAudience' error

```
"error":{"code":"InvalidAudience","message":"The audience claim value is invalid \'https://outlook.sample.com\'"}
```

when calling Outlook REST APIs against one specific mail server (e.g., https://outlook.sample.com).

- [https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview]
- [https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events]

However, based on above configuration and approach, we don't find any issue against Office365 and some other enterprise Exchange servers. Is there any special setting/configuration on Exchange server can resolve the 'InvalidAudience' problem?