# How to get authorization token through OAuth2 and read Outlook emails through http requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I've been retrieving my emails in Outlook by only using python requests to GET the endpoint `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages`

Example code:

```
import requests

requests.get('https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages', auth=(email, pwd))
```

I would get a json object back, parse through it, and get the contents of my email. But now Microsoft has deprecated it and I have been trying to migrate over to using Microsoft Graph. My question is, how do I get an OAuth2 token without having to launch a browser using http requests?

So far I've been reading through the [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/outlook-rest-api-v1-0-basicauth-deprecation/) and registered my "app" (just a regular python script) in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList). Every example that I come across, I always have to go visit an authorization url where I have to manually log in through a front end UI which looks like this:
[image: outlook login]
I want to be able to do this through http requests/without a frontend UI but I can't seem to find any answers on how to do this.

This is the code I have so far:

#### outlook_test.py

```
import requests

authorize_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'

payload = {
        'client_id': app_client_id, # Variable exists but not exposed in this question
        'response_type': 'code',
        'redirect_uri': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient',
        'response_mode': 'form_post',
        'scope': 'mail.read',
        'state': '12345'
        }

r = requests.get(authorize_url, params=payload)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

This is what I get back:

```
200
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scal    able=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedSignIn" />
    <meta name="SiteID" content="" />
    <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
    <meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />

    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/jsdisabled" />
    </noscript>


        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8502.8/co    ntent/images/favicon_a_eupayfgghqiai7k9sol6lg2.ico" />

    <meta name="robots" content="none" />
...
```

This is what I have in my platform settings when I registered my app if it helps:
[image: app platform settings screenshot]

Is there any way I can get the authorization code programatically? I tried passing in the auth parameter as well but that didn't work.

## New Findings

I recently found out that python requests handles OAuth2 but now I am getting a different error when trying to follow [their examples](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow). 
This is the error that I'm getting:

```
  File "outlook_test.py", line 31, in <module>
    token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, auth=auth)
  File "C:\Users\ryee\Documents\gitLabQA\QA_BDD\outlook_env\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 307, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "C:\Users\ryee\Documents\gitLabQA\QA_BDD\outlook_env\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\base.py", line 415, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "C:\Users\ryee\Documents\gitLabQA\QA_BDD\outlook_env\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 425, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "C:\Users\ryee\Documents\gitLabQA\QA_BDD\outlook_env\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 432, in validate_token_parameters
    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
  File "C:\Users\ryee\Documents\gitLabQA\QA_BDD\outlook_env\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\errors.py", line 405, in raise_from_error
    raise cls(**kwargs)
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) AADSTS90014: The required field 'scope' is missing.
Trace ID: 2359d8a6-0140-43c1-8ff5-8103045d2f00
Correlation ID: dff39a1f-ffe1-493e-aea3-1536974b777d
```

I tried `'[Mail.Read]'` as a scope but I'm getting an "Invalid Scope parameter".

My new python script:

#### outlook_test.py

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_app_id, app_secret)
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_app_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, auth=auth)
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Has anyone else faced this issue and is there any workaround? I tried multiple options from Google but had no luck. Unfortunately, I don't have any knowledgeable person in my organization either!

Answer (score 0):

The scope you are using, Mail.Read requires user consent. What you want is Application permission Mail.Read which requires admin consent(This link shows how to get [Admin Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#administrator-consent-experience)). 
You are trying to access a user's messages, thus the user needs to consent to that action.
According to the docs:-
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found this tutorial very helpful for getting access codes:

**This tutorial uses [Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480656/outlook-rest-api-vs-microsoft-graph) (which covers several Microsoft products including Microsoft Outlook) rather than the outlook REST API (which covers just Outlook).**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial

At first, I thought setting up a Django server was overkill. Then I realized that I wanted a way for my Python instance to capture the access code after going through single-sign-on.  (I MUST use my browser for single-sign-on because my institution uses multi-factor authentation.) Having a Django server is a natural way to do this.

So I created a new PyCharm Django project (which is straight-forward in PyCharm) and began following the tutorial.

I found it essential to continue following the tutorial all the way through displaying my emails to avoid getting authentication errors -- deviate from the tutorial, and I got error messages (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878657/invalidaudience-error-returned-when-invoking-outlook-rest-api)) that were unpenetrable.

(I previously posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000674/1048186) in response to a different question.)